# ruby on Rails Rest Api + oAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

hello dear developers!
what are benefits of using rest api + oAuth in Rails 3 ?

### where I can find a code examples of authentication (server + client)

Maybe I should use some different authenication ? 
The main Idea is that clients can buy goods via restfull queries and I should 
provide the highest level of reliability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer but a slight "redirect": Check out the omniauth gem.

Home: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

A fork of the main repository, but more up to date right now: https://github.com/benschwarz/omniauth

While I usually don't like gems because they often cause more trouble than benefit authentication code usually does not get better when I write it myself, and this gem is pretty much standard and very widely used.

Comment: thanks , sorry but I updated my question, have you something to add ?

Comment: The omniauth Wiki has examples - for omniauth, of course. I guess you may have to be more specific, reading the question what I think of is "normal" session management on websites (logged in as some user or not). For that there are examples (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki).